# Customizing Progress Bar and updating text view content simultaneously

Tags: android, textview, progress-bar, ui-thread

I am trying to display the percentage loading of the loading bar and a text view  below it  whose content is changing constantly. I am not able to display both simultaneously. Below is my code . Please help me to figure out the error.Thanks !

```
 mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                       mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                        per.setText(mProgressStatus+" % ");
                        txt.setText("" + random.nextInt(text.length));

                        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 200);   
                      }
               });
            }
```

Comment: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/05/18/custom-progressbar-android-text-part-3/

Comment: @Vera thanks for your answer. But I am able to display percentage only. The text view content is not showing up.

Comment: add a screenshot and show me where the text view is.

Comment: please paste ur code as well